# SELECT clause in Lambda Expression broke in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: .net, select, lambda, expression, recursive-datastructures

I have followings models:

```
  public class Product
  {
     public string ModelNo { set; get; }
     public IList<SubCategory> Categories{ get; set; }
   }

   public class SubCategory
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int SubCategoryID { set; get; }
        public int? ParentSubCategoryID { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCategory> ChildCategory { get; set; }
        public SubCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

I retrieve a product from product repository using following codes:

```
Product prod = prodRepo.FindBy(x=> x.ItemNumber.Equals(modelNum)).AsQueryable()
            .Include(p => p.ProductCategory.Select(x => x.SubCategory))
            .Include(p => p.ProductCategory.Select(x => x.SubCategory.ParentCategory))
            .Include(p => p.ProductCategory.Select(x => x.SubCategory.ChildCategory))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

When a sub category does not have a parent category, the above codes does not return the sub category in .NET 4.5.1. But using .NET 4.0, the sub category with null parent category is returned. Is there a way to solve this in .NET 4.5.1 (i.e. conditional SELECT clause if possible)?